# Capital letters in a string using the 'map' method

Tags: javascript

I want to change to make the first letters of the words in the string uppercase, and after translating into an array, I use the map method. The problem is that inheritance does not work in this method, as I understand it, because when you return the map element, the original string is returned:

```
const str = 'dkdg gkdj wijoerbj'
let r = str.split(' ').map((item, index) => {
    item[0] = item[0].toUpperCase()
    return item
})
```

unchanged first letters will also be returned with such a code entry(is in the map()):

```
item[0] = item[0].toUpperCase()
return item[0]
```

however, when I return the first line, the letters still become uppercase, but I do not know how to return the rest of the word in this case(is in the map()):

```
return item[0] = item[0].toUpperCase()
```

why inheritance does not work as it should, tell me, please, and how to add the rest of the word if there are no other options?

Comment: Strings are immutable. `let str = 'abc'; str[1] = 'd'; console.log(str);` does NOT yield `"adc"`.

Comment: An alternative approach to the problem: `let r = str.replace(/\b\w/g,l=>l.toUpperCase());` -- much simpler :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**We can do this with two array map methods as bellow.**

```js
const str = 'dkdg gkdj wijoerbj';

let r = str.split(' ').map((item, index) => {
    return ([...item].map((letter, i) => {
        return (i == 0) ? letter.toUpperCase() : letter;
    })).join('');
});


console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cancat the first letter with rest of the string. Also these two lines `item[0] = item[0].toUpperCase();return item` though will convert the first letter to uppercase but it will still return the original sting because `item` represent the original word nut not the modified text

```js
const str = 'dkdg gkdj wijoerbj'
let r = str.split(' ').map((item, index) => {

  return item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.substring(1, item.length)
});


console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const str = 'dkdg gkdj wijoerbj'
let r = str.split(' ').map(x=> x[0].toLocaleUpperCase());
console.log(r)
```

u can try this code to get first letters of the words in the string uppercase into new arry using map and returns capital letter of each first letter